# How do I lookup DomainRuntimeServiceMBean from JNDI from a Local Connection?

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

#### I have searched the Weblogic documentation extensively:

All the documentation on the Oracle site and all the examples I have found so far only show how to get a reference to this MBean via a Remote connection or to an instance of `MBeanServer` locally.

The little bit that mentions a local connection is vague and incomplete:

> Absolute JNDI name of the MBean server. The JNDI name must start with
>   `/jndi/` and be followed by one of the JNDI names described in Table
>   4-1.

Table 4-1 shows:

```
MBean Server                  JNDI Name
Domain Runtime MBean Server   weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime
```

This doesn't work, I tried dumping the JNDI tree and can't find anything relevant in there.

I am on the `AdminServer` so that isn't the issue.

What I can find instructions to do that works is getting a reference to an instance of `MBServer`, but that isn't what I need; example: `(MBeanServer) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/domainRuntime");`

But this doesn't do me any good, it is an instance of `MBeanServer` and I don't want to dig through all the indirection with the `ObjectName` stuff.

#### What I need to reference is DomainRuntimeServiceMBean interface:

What I need is to be able to get an instance of `DomainRuntimeServiceMBean` - [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/management/mbeanservers/domainruntime/DomainRuntimeServiceMBean.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answer

The *type safe* interfaces are all Deprecated, you have to do the lookup/tree walking manually.

> As of 9.0, the MBeanHome interface and all type-safe interfaces for
>   WebLogic Server MBeans are deprecated. Instead, JMX applications that
>   interact with WebLogic Server MBeans should use standard JMX design
>   patterns in which clients use the
>   javax.management.MBeanServerConnection interface to discover MBeans,
>   attributes, and attribute types at runtime.

#### Long Answer

```
private InitialContext ctx;
private MBeanServer domain;
private ObjectName domainObjectName;
```

In the constructor:

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
this.domain = (MBeanServer) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/domainRuntime");
this.domainObjectName = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean");
```

In your method:

```
final ObjectName dr = (ObjectName) this.domain.getAttribute(domainObjectName, "DomainRuntime");
final ObjectName dm = (ObjectName) this.domain.getAttribute(dr, "DeploymentManager");
final ObjectName[] adrs = (ObjectName[]) this.domain.getAttribute(dm, "AppDeploymentRuntimes");
for (final ObjectName on : adrs)
{
    if (this.domain.getAttribute(on, "ApplicationName").equals(appName))
    {
        this.domain.invoke(on, "stop", null, null);
        break;
    }
}
```

#### Of course now I have to write my own convenience classes that are typesafe to wrap all this verbose non-sense!